# Where do we request changes to the site?

Tags: feature-request

I don't so much have a question as a proposal that I'd really like to see effected. I'd like to argue for and push for longer tags to enable clear full titles with expansions, as squashing under the limit and having to clarify the game name in my body is annoying. Where is the proper place to do this? I figured meta is obviously good for questions but guessing it's not the proper place to outright propose changes such as these.  Is simply tagging it feature-request sufficient? Didn't seem so.

Comment: Are there any specific examples you've found where the 25 character limit has caused problems?

Comment: Well, board games often are long names and clunky to shorten. Why do it? to improve readability? The argument for concise variables in programming works for me because they are embedded in a 'sentence' structure of sorts in code logic and can get really verbose in that context, but, here, the tags are typed once and neatly arranged in one place. I feel there's a clear way to identify and search when we're expected to simply type some or all of the game title instead of having potential conflicts or incorrect matches when someone searches settlers looking for a different game.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but I'm curious to know if there were specific situations that you've run into where you felt that there definitely needed to be more characters. Was there a certain game?

Comment: My previous comment is rooted without knowledge of how the tag system works with regard to searching of course. I think it just feels simple to write Arkham Horror Curse Of The Dark Pharaoh and see hits specifically related to it and how many questions pertaining to it, than search for titles that intersect and collecting questions about different games under the same tag potentially.  I read it was a hard limit to change in the codebase so the gripe is minor enough that it sounded not worth pursuing in the end.

Comment: In answer to your followup, I don't think any situation made me feel i *had* to have 25+ characters. It was mostly just not liking seeing an abbreviation for a title that wasn't the title of the game. Maybe the search function for tags is loose enough that they will catch minor problems and provide good results regardless.

Comment: One situation that recently came up, I wanted to add 'the-captain-is-dead-adrift' (expansion to The Captain Is Dead), but couldn't because of the limit, so I had added 'the-captain-is-dead-ep2' but this seems clunky. What do people do if ep2 doesn't even fit? Do I have separately 'the-captain-is-dead' and 'adrift' or 'expansion-adrift'? Obviously if there is a game called adrift, there is now a conflict that obscures the tag. The tag I added asked me to create a tag wiki, and I didn't like the thought of creating one for two conflicting possibilities. I'll probably go with 'expansion-adrift'.

Comment: I also notice that when I change it to "captain-is-dead-adrift" (removing the "the" just to make it fit), searching with "the captain is dead" fails to find the question.  That seems like a quality of the search feature that doesn't jive with having to improvise (cut off words, abbreviate) the tags like this. If I had to abbreviate something like "Curse of the Dark Pharaoh" to "Curse of Dark Pharaoh" to fit a tag restriction, I'd hope the search feature would be a little looser and trigger a hit despite the query containing a term that wasn't in the tag.

Comment: That does make sense. Since this question already has an accepted answer, perhaps it would be good to raise a new question if it is difficult or impossible to find specific games using search because of the tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the spot.  The site admins will see everything tagged [feature-request](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).  There is no guarantee that they will respond, though.

This has been [status-declined](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) on meta.stackexchange.com in the past - [Raising the 25 chars limit for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags)

Comment: Thanks, I also see the issue being more relevantly put forth here http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters. I guess this will not be happening.